# How do I use / interpret vi shortcuts on linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I've found myself in the dreadful predicament of having to use vi, and I don't understand [this list of shortcuts for it.](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)

I'm in `insert` mode, and I want to save the changes that I've made so far and exit.

The shortcut for saving changes seems to be `:w<Return>`

---

How is this shortcut done? I understand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> ; I have no idea how `:` , `w` , and `Return` are put together into one shortcut.

Comment: After beginning to use linux from the command line, I just want to say "Thank you" to the generation before me for the layer of abstraction that you put in place to save me this trouble up to this point.

Comment: ESC to put you in command mode, then :wq to write then exit.

Comment: Okk, so in command mode I just type that string. Is there any confirmation key, or does the shortcut string trigger itself? Never mind, I understand, it puts me on the command line. I imagined it was sort of an invisible functionality. @suspectus

Comment: The RETURN key terminates the string, the commands are then actioned.

Comment: @jt0dd - your welcome!

Comment: Be careful!!! If you get used to the awesomeness of vi (vim) you will curse using any other text editor

Comment: @Bruno9779 Maybe so, if I have any time left once I get done editing the first document.

Comment: It can be a pain to get started. Vi is not user friendly and it is not intuitive. But it is fast, powerful and has very interesting features. I remember there was a package to have some sort of mouse integration in vim, it might be a good idea to look it up. Also, vim (vi improved) is a tiny bit easier to use then vi.

Comment: @Bruno9779 My main issue is the fragility of the system. My console crashed during editing once, now restoring the file fails, editing, etc. Been stuck on that for days now. I'll have to post a question on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These shortcuts are not key combos, but key *sequences*.

To save your current work you would first use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave `insert` mode.

Then press <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> in succession.

In `vi`there are many commands that are key sequences instead of combos, though both exist.

Personally I think [Engadget VIM 101](http://www.engadget.com/2012/07/10/vim-how-to/) is a good introduction to `vim` (which is vi improved, and probably what you want).